# Microsoft CRM SQL Connection Error

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When I try to save a new entity I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. With error code - -2147220970.

How do I go about troubleshooting this error?

thanks

Comment: Please share a few more details: deployment (OnPremise/Online), product version, custom parts (e.g. plugins, synchronous workflows). Common sources of SQLExceptions are plugins causing deadlocks, full transaction logs a.o.

Comment: OnPremise, 2015. there are 5 Plug In assemblies. I am very new to CRM so not sure what synchronous workflows are. I think our solution is a fairly basic one.

Comment: Switch on tracing on your CRM application server. Logs appear in the program files folder of Dynamics CRM. You will find more details there. It's also useful to inspect the SQL Server logs.

Answer (score 0):

This error corresponds to "public const int UnExpected = unchecked((int)0x80040216); // -2147220970" when looking at the errorcodes.cs in the CRM 2015 SDK in the SDK\SampleCode\CS\HelperCode\ directory.  That being said, as mentioned in a couple of the comments, this is likely corresponding to either a Microsoft SQL Timeout and/or SQL Deadlocks.  You should also review the Microsoft CRM Server application event logs.  Event ID 17972 for the MSCRMPlatform source corresponds with a CRM query that took longer than 10 seconds and will include the full text of the query.  Note that if there was SQL Deadlocks or long running SQL Blocking during the time of creating the new entity, that queries that show up as being long running may not necessarily be expensive SQL queries, but just happened to get caught up behind that blocking which prevented them from being executed quickly.

Without knowing full details of your SQL Server environment and customizations,   I would increase the timeout that Microsoft Dynamics CRM uses for these platform generated queries.  The default if you haven't changed it is a 30 second timeout for CRM Generated SQL queries.

I would increase the timeout to a value of **600** decimal by running RegEdit on the Microsoft CRM Server and adding the registry key below (as a REG_DWORD KEY).  Note that if increase this a lot more, that it can be done as it represents the timeout value in seconds, but I typically never recommend this being set much higher than 600 decimal at most unless you are doing something like importing a Microsoft CRM Organization or updating from an older version.  If Microsoft CRM queries take longer than that to execute, then you need to identify and tune those queries and/or tune the performance of your Microsoft SQL Server.  It would take much more space than I have for this answer, but if you want a good tool and reference for SQL Server data collection and tuning, I'd start with the SQLNexus tool and the PSS Perf Wait Stats data collection scripts that you can read up on and download from this link:  http://sqlnexus.codeplex.com/

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSCRM\OLEDbTimeout